# Not precompile on certain assets - Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

I have a RoR project in which i have several assets that i don't want them to be precompiled in production mode. These assets are compound by JS/CSS files and currently they are placed under app/assets/javascript/ism/.

Actually, it's the whole ism folder which i don't want to compile. Though in development mode it's useful and comfortable to keep those files there to work with them, in production mode they shouldn't be there. In production mode those files are all compiled (externally) in a separate file which is served by S3 ant not from RoR/Nginx. The externally compiled file is even linked manually, not by RoR.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s3.blabla.com/file_compiled.js"></script>
```

So, what should it be the best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's less than perfect, however you can prevent these files from being compiled by moving the  ism directory out of the asset pipeline and serving them statically. E.g moving `/app/assets/javascript/ism/` to `/public/ism/`.

If you don't want these files on production at all, you could simply add `public/ism/*` to your `.gitignore` file (assuming you're using git).

Comment: That's what i guessed. So should i link them manually in the .html where i want to put them on, shouldn't i? Sounds good. I should even include those links within a conditional statement to avoid them in production mode.

In the other hand, I'd like to ignore them in Git, but i work in group. Therefore those files have to be synced...

Comment: Yeah that could work, in the layout template, maybe something like:

    `<% if Rails.env.development? %> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/public/ism/{{JSFILE}}"></script>
    <% end %>`